# Bolean algebra De morgan's law - can i use it from the outside to the inside like I did?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, education, boolean-algebra

I thought maybe the problem is because I used the morgan from the outside , I tried figuring out the problem for an hour and solved it like three times. I found some mistakes but thats the finale answer- and its not right....
why is it, does the morgan law has problems here in the way i did it ?
[How I tried to slove the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SU3f.jpg)

[solution of my teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT3Zi.png)

what is the problem with my solution?

$ABCD+\overline{\overline{A}*\overline{C}+A*\overline{B}+\overline{B*\overline{C}}}$

$ABCD+(A'C'+((AB')')*(B*C'))'$

$=ABCD+(A'C')'*(A*B')+B*C'+(B*C')'$

$ABCD+(A+C)*(A*B')+(B*C')'$

$ABCD+AB'+AB'C+\overline{BC'}$

$ABCD+AB'(1+C)+\overline{B*C'}$

$A(BCD+B')+B'+C=A(B'+CD)+B'+C=AB'+ACD+B'+C
=B'(A+1)+C(AD+1)=B'+C$

Comment: Your blue one is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the first replay.What is the problem with the blue one?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the formulas in your MSE questions. It is easy to learn and saves users who want to read your questions a lot of trouble. It is also a good way of getting started with $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$: the standard tools for presenting mathematics in the scientific literature.

Comment: I dont know how to use it , can you just answer my question. Its an easy question I just dont get the problem

Comment: "It is easy to learn and saves users who want to read your questions a lot of trouble. "

Comment: Thats not easy to learn,even to post here is not easy and it took me 20 minutes untill the cursed system allowed me to upload the question. Whats the problem with good quality screenshots ? If I have something very long, why do I need to write it all over again in a strange language?>

Comment: Remember that people here are not paid to help you.  The easier you make it for us, the more likely we will be to help.  I never look beyond the post.  The question is clearly presented here or I don't look.

Comment: you are realy not friendly to  newcomers thats only my first question! I dont find how to put NOT on the boolean algebra on mathjax- does it sound reasoable that I upload a question and it takes me an hour just to write it. How do you  expect new guys to enter this place?  most of people will just give up  for the difficulty in this site

Comment: An easier notation for negation or complement is the prime symbol, that is, $A'$ or $(X+Y)'$ in place of $\overline{A}$ or $\overline{X+Y}$. So your original expression would be typeset as `$ABCD+(A'C'+(AB'+B'+C)')'$`, giving $ABCD+(A'C'+(AB'+B'+C)')'$

Comment: I dont find in mathjax tuturial how to put a **not** symbole above ABCD

Comment: If you insist with the bar, then $\overline{X+Y}$ can be obtained as `$\overline{X+Y}$`.

Comment: thanks man, yes I insist for the bar because otherwise I cant understand the equations well...

Comment: I thin you will eventually find it cumbersome, but that's up to you

Comment: Thats crazy to use  mathjax its realy timeconsuming, only to write the first equation is so long!!!!!

Comment: you may also find useful [this site](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). You draw a symbol in the box and it gives you several alternatives of what it might be, with code and corresponding symbol

Comment: It's crazy trying to walk, when we do it in the first place. Crawling is so much easier... But now I prefer to walk.

Comment: Yes man, but I have exam tommorow and instead of learning for it I learn how to mathjax in order people here help me...

Comment: Can you help me now?

Comment: The OP's question is $ABCD+\overline{\overline{A}*\overline{C}+A*\overline{B}+\overline{B*\overline{C}}}$ whereas the teacher's is $ABCD+\overline{\overline{A}*\overline{C}+\overline{A*\overline{B}+\overline{B*\overline{C}}}}$

Comment: It may not help you for this particular exam, but this site is a good resource for learning mathematics (especially if you're taking a class at the same time IMO). I'd recommend asking questions about things that you don't understand when you don't have an upcoming test. Even after you learn Mathjax, asking a question on this site takes about 20-40 minutes and you may not get an answer for a few hours or days (although that's unusual). The cost in time may not be worth it close to a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the problem with my solution?

The very start.

> > $ABCD+\overline{\overline{A}*\overline{C}+A*\overline{B}+\overline{B*\overline{C}}}$
> >
> > $ABCD+(A'C'+((AB')')*(B*C'))'$

It should be: $ABCD+{({A'}{C'}+A\cdot{B'}+{(B\cdot{C'})'})'}$